# Interference between two sorts - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I wrote an AJAX filter search with town select box.

The user chooses a town from the select box, submits and then the results appear.

Result is a table and a list of items - both of them have the same values, the table appears in a modal.

Each item has a checkbox. If a checkbox is checked, the item from table and list items is shown on its wrapper in the modal. table items shown in: `.en-ads-modal__table--body` and list items goes to `.en-ads-modal__list`

I'm about to sort each item by `data-town` for both `.en-ads-modal__table--body` and `.en-ads-modal__list`. as I do this it works fine but I have an annoying bug that make my modal messy:

For example if

```
items:(
    ( 
      item1: data-town="46", 
      item2: data-town="26", 
      item4: data-town="55",
     )
)
```

are added to the modal, if user wants to search in new town, and add another item for example `item6: data-town="188"`, the sort will mess up.
(item1 for example is name of the item and the number is the date-town value)

this is what I coded so far:

```js
const $modalListTable = $('.en-ads-modal__table--body');
const $modalList = $('.en-ads-modal__list');
const $checkboxes = $('.ad-item__info--add-to-modal').change(function() {

  //check an item in quick edit will check same item in list and table and vice versa
  $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);

  //add items to modal
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    //for list
    $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').closest('.ad-item').addClass("ad-item--add-to-pdf");
    //for table
    $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').closest('.table__ad-item').addClass("ad-item--add-to-pdf");
  } else {
    //for list
    $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').closest('.ad-item').removeClass("ad-item--add-to-pdf");
    //for table
    $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').closest('.table__ad-item').removeClass("ad-item--add-to-pdf");
  }


  /************************************************************* MUST FIX CONFLICT BETWEEN MODAL LIST AND MODAL TABLE *******************************************************************/

  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('town') - $(b).data('town');
  }
  //add items to modal table 
  let modalTableContent = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, cb) => $(cb).closest('.table__ad-item').clone()).get();
  modalTableContent.sort(sort_li); //sort by data-town
  $modalListTable.html(modalTableContent);


  //add items to modal (list items)
  let modalContent = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, cb) => $(cb).closest('.ad-item').clone()).get();
  modalContent.sort(sort_li); //sort by data-town
  $modalList.html(modalContent);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--first result html when user select a specific town and submit the form-->
<div id="ajax-filter-search-results">
   <div class="ajax-filter-search-results__table">
      <div class="ajax-filter-search-results__table--body">
         <ul class="table__ad-item"
             data-id="1914"
             data-town="46">
            <li>
               <p>town a</p>
               <p>billboard 1</p>
            </li>
            <li class="ajax-filter-search-results__table--body-checkbox">
               <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         value="1914"
                         class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
                  add to modal</label>
            </li>
         </ul>

         <ul class="table__ad-item"
             data-id="1909"
             data-town="46">
            <li>
               <p>town a</p>
               <p>billboard 2</p>
            </li>
            <li class="ajax-filter-search-results__table--body-checkbox">
               <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         value="1909"
                         class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
                  add to modal</label>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
   <ul class="ajax-filter-search-results__list">
      <li class="ad-item"
          data-id="1914"
          data-town="46">
               <p>town a</p>
               <p>billboard 1</p>
         <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value="1914"
                   class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
            add to modal</label>

      </li>
      <li class="ad-item"
          data-id="1909"
          data-town="46">
               <p>town a</p>
               <p>billboard 2</p>
         <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value="1909"
                   class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
            add to modal</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<hr>

<!--modal wrapper when user checked each checkbox (in this example user searched from diffrent towns and select some itmes of each town -->
<div id="ajax-filter-search-results">
   <div class="en-ads-modal__table">
      <ul class="en-ads-modal__table--header">
         <li>town</li>
         <li>billboard</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="en-ads-modal__table--body">
         <ul class="table__ad-item"
             data-id="1909"
             data-town="46">
            <li>
               <p>town a</p>
               <p>billboard 2</p>
            </li>
            <li class="ajax-filter-search-results__table--body-checkbox">
               <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         value="1909"
                         class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
                  add to modal</label>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="table__ad-item ad-item--add-to-pdf"
             data-id="1920"
             data-town="26">
            <li>
               <p>town b</p>
               <p>billboard 67</p>
            </li>
            <li class="ajax-filter-search-results__table--body-checkbox">
               <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         value="1920"
                         class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
                  add to modal</label>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="table__ad-item ad-item--add-to-pdf"
             data-id="1120"
             data-town="26">
            <li>
               <p>town c</p>
               <p>billboard 11</p>
            </li>
            <li class="ajax-filter-search-results__table--body-checkbox">
               <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
                  <input type="checkbox"
                         value="1120"
                         class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
                  add to modal</label>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <ul class="en-ads-modal__list">
      <li class="ad-item ad-item--add-to-pdf"
          data-id="1909"
          data-town="46">
               <p>town a</p>
               <p>billboard 2</p>
         <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value="1909"
                   class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
            add to modal</label>
      </li>
      <li class="ad-item ad-item--add-to-pdf"
          data-id="1920"
          data-town="26">
               <p>town b</p>
               <p>billboard 67</p>
         <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value="1909"
                   class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
            add to modal</label>
      </li>
      <li class="ad-item ad-item--add-to-pdf"
          data-id="1120"
          data-town="55">
               <p>town c</p>
               <p>billboard 11</p>
         <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   value="1120"
                   class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
            add to modal</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I didn't include the HTML, because it's confusing.

I found out that if I delete the table sort method, the list sort works well. I don't know why two sorting is not working well even the wrappers are different.

Any idea what makes this buggy?

**Update:** I have no idea if it could help but I update my code as some people wants the first search result and modal. It's the shortest html that I can write. sorry!

Comment: Welcome! Please include some minimal HTML so we can debug this. Currently we have no way to test this.

Comment: Your code same ha javascript that does nothing because it finds no matching HTML elements. No one can answer your question without the HTML. If the HTML in your project is messy, clean it up. You don't need to do a full copy/paste, just include enough to make your code snippet work.  A minimal amount

Comment: Dear disinfor and @ChrisBarr, I have no idea if it could help but I update my code as some people wants the first search result and modal. It's the shortest html that I can write. sorry!

Comment: @Alipvd So now that it has HTML, when you press that blue "Run Code Snippet" button, does it reproduce the issue you have described? I see some checkboxes I can check and uncheck, but nothing else happens. Is this the issue you are having?

Comment: @Alipvd I'm trying to figure this out, but your JS references `.en-ads-modal__table--body` and `.en-ads-modal__list` elements, but your HTML does not include these anywhere.  Please add enough HTML to make your code work.  No one can help you unless you can demonstrate the issue you are having. Please make it **easy** for people to help you

Comment: @ChrisBarr sorry. I update my code. However I said before that I write a full program that have over 1000 line of code, so you can't test the code from here. I just want to know why the two sorts are Interference even the html are diffrent.